# Render Page using ApostropheCMS Language

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I know this kind of stupid question to ask . But for beginners and familiar with express nodejs , this question might found useful to others as well. For me , I am familiar rendering nunjucks with this method by using express nodejs. Here is an example that we all know about it :

```
nunjucks.render('index.html', { foo: 'bar' });
```

And I found your Apostrophe Docs on this [documentation](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-module/index.html#render) that using `render(req, name, data)` . I want to customize my cursor and **override** `req.data` like using nunjucks above . And I found out that [this](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-module/index.html#partial) is the right method to use and I don't know where to start ! Should I use `self.beforeShow` ? I don't want to use `self.route` where GET request are taking place. I just want to add additional data and render it on `show.html` , `indexAjax.html` or even using a custom `indexCustom.html` using similar as Nunjucks example above. I know how to do cursor and manipulate the data by it. I'm a slow learner but I never stop learning. Thank you in advance.

> P/s : If you guys can post a new tutorial at HOWTO section for this "extra rendering/override data into the page" , that would be extremely helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make additional data available to your page templates, the easiest way is to listen for the `apostrophe-pages:beforeSend` promise event (with Apostrophe 2.63.0 or newer):

```
// in app.js

var apos = require('apostrophe')({
  shortName: 'myproject',
  // among other things
  modules: {
    'apostrophe-pieces': {}
  }
});

// in lib/modules/products/index.js


module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  name: 'product',
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.on('apostrophe-pages:beforeSend', 'getAllProducts', function(req) {
      // Let's assume you have a "products" module that extends pieces
      // and you want all of them on every page (not necessarily a good idea)
      return self.apos.modules.products.find(req).toArray().then(function(products) {
        req.data.products = products;
      });
    });
  }  
};

{# In any page template or layout #}

{% for product in data.products %}
  {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

The older way is to implement a `pageBeforeSend` method, but that forces you to use callbacks, and promises are definitely the 2018 way to go.

You didn't specify anything more about your use case, so my example here is a method that extends pieces in the usual way, but makes sure all the pieces are available on every page - which could be a good idea or a terrible one, depending on how many you have, but it demonstrates the technique.

Comment: May I ask . What are the arguments that available on self.on ? First argument is to call **apostrophe-pages** module with after ":" which is a **method** call? And what is **'getAllProducts'** argument is for ? It's like apos.singleton(data.page , **'getAllProducts'** , 'widget-name') ? I really want to know the arguments . If the first argument is that i get to call ANY MODULE with method , that should apply too , right ? Or it only works on **apostrophe-pages** module ?

Comment: The `getAllProducts` is the name you are assigning to the brand new method of your module that self.on conveniently creates for you using the function in the third argument. It is exactly equivalent to writing "self.getAllProducts = ... code here ...; self.on('apostrophe-pages:beforeSend', 'getAllProducts').

Comment: The first argument is the name of a module and an event that that module emits. Some modules emit events, others don't. apostrophe-pages emits beforeSend which is particularly useful because it is emitted just before a page is rendered and is your last chance to do asynchronous work in JavaScript.

We are in the process of writing up a complete guide to the standard events that are emitted and can be listened for in this way.

Comment: Wow , thank you ! This new features promise event is definitely useful ! Thanks again for the help and provide deep explanation to it.